# Como agregar un valor a un campo td en una tabla en html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Me pasaron una página desarrollada en .asp .net en la cual tienen generada una tabla, esta obviamente está ya formateada como corresponde.
Los campos que tiene una fila **tr** son los siguientes:

```
<tr class="filafondo">
   <td>1</td>
   <td>10688</td>
   <td>Budin</td>
   <td>UM</td>
   <td>1,000</td>
   <td>0</td>
   <td>1.380</td>
   <td>1.380</td>
   <td>7</td>
   <td>1280</td>
   <td>6</td>
   <td>645554001488</td>
   <td>0,9105</td>
   <td>0,9105</td>
</tr>
```

¿Existe alguna forma, ya sea con jquery o javascript de ponerle un valor a una etiqueta **td** predeterminada? En este caso sería el 6to *td*, el que tiene valor 0.

Buscando en internet encontré este código:

```
function setRowPrice(tableId, rowId, colNum, newValue)
{
    $('#'+table).find('tr#'+rowId).find('td:eq(colNum)').html(newValue);
};
```

Acorde a los datos que pide, tengo:

1. El ID de la tabla.
2. No trabajo con un id de fila por lo que, ¿esto se puede cambiar por una clase?. De ser así esta sería la forma correcta? -> **.find('tr.'+rowId)**
3. **colNum** hacer referencia a la ubicación del td, supongo que este también va desde 0 a la posición N, para este caso sería 5
4. **newValue**, este lo voy a sacar un campo input que tengo

Existe otra forma de hacer esto o voy bien encaminado?

Muchas Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

### Respuesta corta

Esto te debería valer:

`$('.filafondo > td:eq(5)').html(nuevoValor);`

### Respuesta larga

Con JavaScript puedes usar `document.getElementsByTagName` para obtener los elementos con cierta etiqueta. Si tu código es sencillo como en tu ejemplo te servirá, pero para páginas más complejas no es tan fácil, será mejor usar la clase (abajo ejemplos de esto).

```js
var columnas = document.getElementsByTagName('td');

columnas[1].innerHTML = 'B';
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Esta otra solución es más conveniente porque usas la clase, es más específico, pero seguirás teniendo el problema de si hay varias filas con la misma clase (si solo tienes una, considera usar una ID).

Sin jQuery:

```js
var filafondo = document.getElementsByClassName('filafondo');

filafondo[0].children[5].innerHTML = 'CAMBIADO';
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table id="id-tabla">
  <tr class="filafondo">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>10688</td>
    <td>Budin</td>
    <td>UM</td>
    <td>1,000</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>1.380</td>
    <td>1.380</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>1280</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>645554001488</td>
    <td>0,9105</td>
    <td>0,9105</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Con jQuery:

```js
$('.filafondo > td:eq(5)').html('CAMBIADO');
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="id-tabla">
  <tr id='i' class="filafondo">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>10688</td>
    <td>Budin</td>
    <td>UM</td>
    <td>1,000</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>1.380</td>
    <td>1.380</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>1280</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>645554001488</td>
    <td>0,9105</td>
    <td>0,9105</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: voy a probar la opción sin jquery, en tu código usas **filafondo[0]**, ese 0 yo lo puedo trabajar con otra variable en la que guardo la fila donde hago click

Comment: Date cuenta que la función `getElementsByClassName` está en plural. La traducción sería: `dameElementosPorNombreDeClase`, o sea, te va a coger todos los elementos que tengan esa clase. Si hay 4, entonces te devolverá una lista de 4 elementos. Por eso uso `filafondo[0]`. Entonces, si tienes más de 1 elemento con esa clase, tendrías que averiguar cuál es el elemento que te interesa y acceder a él. Yo he supuesto que `filafondo` solo habrá una, así que accedo al primer y único elemento de la lista. Tendrás que comprobar si es así o no.

Answer (score 0):

Este Ejemplo, pepara la tabla con attributos. El selector es más facil de entender y es mas determinista.

Un Saludo

```js
 var tableId = 'id-tabla';
var rowId = 2;
var colNum = 3;
 
 $( document ).ready(function() {
 

  $.each($('#'+tableId+' tr'), function(index, value){
      $(value).attr('row-id', index);      
      
      $.each( $( 'td', value), function(tdIndex,tdValue) {
      
        $(tdValue).attr('td-id', tdIndex);
    
      });
    });

  
     
    var newValue = '[Init Value]';

    $('#'+tableId+' tr[row-id='+rowId+'] td[td-id='+colNum+']').html(newValue);

    });

function setValue() {
// No necesitas hacer varios find, esta forma solo haces un query.

    var rowId = 2;
    var colNum = 3;
    var newValue = '[set Value]';

    $('#'+tableId+' tr[row-id='+rowId+'] td[td-id='+colNum+']').html(newValue);
}
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <table id='id-tabla'>
      <tr id='row1'>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>10688</td>
        <td>Budin</td>
        <td>UM</td>
        <td>1,000</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1.380</td>
        <td>1.380</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>1280</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>645554001488</td>
        <td>0,9105</td>
        <td>0,9105</td>
      </tr>
       <tr id='row2'>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>10688</td>
        <td>Budin</td>
        <td>UM</td>
        <td>1,000</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1.380</td>
        <td>1.380</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>1280</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>645554001488</td>
        <td>0,9105</td>
        <td>0,9105</td>
      </tr>
       <tr id='row3'>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>10688</td>
        <td>Budin</td>
        <td>UM</td>
        <td>1,000</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1.380</td>
        <td>1.380</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>1280</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>645554001488</td>
        <td>0,9105</td>
        <td>0,9105</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    
    <input type="button" onclick="setValue()" value="Set Value"/>
```

Comment: Estoy probando tu código pero me tira un error, es este:

**Excepción no controlada en línea 1864, columna 2 en http://localhost:49420/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js
0x800a139e - Error en tiempo de ejecución de JavaScript: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #[object HTMLTableElement], #row1, td:eq(5)**

Pero creo que tiene más que ver con la versión de jquery asi que voy a buscar a qué se debe.

Comment: La fila tiene que tener Id <tr id='row1'>

Comment: Estas usando una biblioteca de jquery bastante antigua, deberías  actualizarla.

Comment: si lo tengo claro, pero para el año que implementaron esta aplicación estaban con esa versión y si la cambio se caen varias funciones, estoy tratando de hacer todo lo que pueda para que con los cambios funcione bien. Sé que no es la mejor opción pero no tengo otra

Comment: Cree un ejemplo que puedes ver trabajando.

Comment: está buena tu respuesta pero por como hicieron la tabla, cómo se van generando los **tr** con la información no puedo ponerle un id como tu me comentas, puedo poner el código pero creo que ya esa sería otra pregunta

Comment: Siempre puedes usar atributos y generarlos dinámicamente.  En vez de Id. Los Id tienen como problemas que solo pueden ser usados una vez, pero el query por ID es el más rápido, por el carácter único que tiene. Por otro lado puedes usar el operador eq() también para la fila.

Comment: Nuevo ejemplo donde se prepara la tabla.

Answer (score -1):

Con el selector de hijos `:nth-child` lo tienes más fácil:

```
   document.querySelector('tr.filafondo td:nth-child(6)').innerText = 'nuevo valor';
```